# Memory leak in my PyGObject project - related to InitiallyUnowned?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I'm seeing memory leaks in my PyGObject project that I do not fully understand.

I was hopefully able to condense it to some sample code. It creates instances of some `Box` class in a for-loop.
For each iteration but the first one, it adds the new box into the previous one, and also creates an object reference into the other direction.

I would then expect that the garbage collector is able to clean up all that mess automatically.

This is the code:

```
import gi  # gtk stuff
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

import weakref

counter = 0

def dec_counter():
    global counter
    counter -= 1

lastbox = None

for i in range(2000):
    newbox = Box()  # ... or Gtk.Box
    if lastbox:
        newbox._foo = lastbox
        lastbox.add(newbox)
    counter += 1
    weakref.finalize(newbox, dec_counter)
    lastbox = newbox

newbox = lastbox = None

gc.collect()
print(counter)
```

That works indeed fine if you have a `Box` class like this:

```
class Box:

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

    def add(self, item):
        self.children.append(item)
```

However, it does not work here when this is a Gtk `Box`.

There seems to be some kind of imperfection in how Gtk memory management is integrated into Python by PyGObject.
Somewhat unfortunate if so, but maybe there is no way around... But at least I need to understand more about the reason
and possible options.

Note: Putting more manual effort into cleaning up references manual at some moment is not what I'm looking for.
Sure, I could do that, but that doesn't scale well if you constantly have to add tons of tricky but boilerplate-y code
for cleanup.

One more thing: When I modify my loop code slightly, so it remembers the first box, and then in the end I call `destroy` on that box,
things are also fine.

One thought that might be related, or complete stupid nonsense:

In the API reference I see a subclass named `InitiallyUnowned`.
Does it maybe have something to do with that?
So it especially happens when I create Gtk objects and then drop them without using it?!

But if so, isn't there a way to make that behave better in my case? Could I somehow just always drop that initial
floating reference and just rely on having a reference to it on Python side (assuming that I create everything in code
and not in xml)?

Comment: Have you tried appending all the boxes to a list? Just curious. It would also be nice if you could provide a [example]; the code you have won't run without adding a bunch of Gtk stuff. Are you putting the boxes in a window, and could you show us how you're doing that?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Hi. I think that code should run in isolation as it is; why not? But yes, you need to import Gtk somewhere, as my issue seems to be more Gtk specific. Does it help when I add the import statement? To your other questions: No, I do not put them in a window in that sample. And what do you mean with adding the boxes to a list? Just to some new list? That will just make one more reference, probably not solving the issue, right?